# Why can you only #define an NSString constant in a header file?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

A curious objective-c newbie question. I noticed that I can #define an NSString in the .h file, but not in the .m file... why?

The declaration in question is:

```
#define kSomeString @"This is a string"
```

That declaration fails with an error if its in the .m file.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: +1 @JamesMcLaughlin.  It should work exactly the same whether it's in the header or the implementation file.  The compiler certainly doesn't care.

Comment: @CarlNorum i can confirm your result, NO ERRORS. Matthew Carriere, something must be wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3):

you CAN define them also in the implementation files.

```
#import "SAiPadHomeViewController.h"

#define hugo @"Test"

@interface SAiPadHomeViewController ()
@end

@implementation SAiPadHomeViewController
@end
```

This example works - try it.

Greetz!